Create Index without name while creating table
I have following temporary table with index. This works since I explicitly name it as IX_#Final_1.
How do I create the index without explicit name?
CREATE TABLE [#Test1]
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Member_BK] VARCHAR(20),
    [Company] VARCHAR(20),
    [Facility_Name] VARCHAR(200),

    INDEX [IX_#Final_1] ([Member_BK], [Company])
)

I need this because of the issues outlined in dba.stackexchange.com - There is already an object named PK_MyPrimaryKey in the database ( primary index on temp table)

I don't get it...if you can explicitly choose the index name, then why can't you use a name not having any conflict?

The CREATE TABLE syntax only supports implicit names (every index gets a name whether you supply one or not) for PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE constraints. If it's meant to be a unique index then drop the name and replace INDEX with the UNIQUE keyword, e.g.: db<>fiddle.

"There is already an object named PK_TempId in the database" is about creating a constraint. For indexes there is no such requirement that the name be unique within a schema. It only needs to be unique within each table

To workaround these problems you can append the name of the SP that is creating the table to the name of the index.

You don't "need" it at all, much pile you don't "need" a hammer to put a screw in the wall. You should always be giving your objects explicit names, not relying on the implicit ones.

@ThomA - This is not true for constraints in temporary tables created by stored procs. They should always use implict names as otherwise you can only create one instance of the table and attempts to execute the proc concurrently will fail due to this reason and explicit constraint names also  prevent temp table object caching


I need this because of the issues outlined in dba.stackexchange.com -
There is already an object named PK_MyPrimaryKey in the database (
primary index on temp table)

No you don't. This fails (with error "There is already an object named 'PK1' in the database.").
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #T1, #T2

CREATE TABLE #T1 ([ID] INT CONSTRAINT PK1 PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TABLE #T2 ([ID] INT CONSTRAINT PK1 PRIMARY KEY)

As it creates a constraint and a corresponding object in sys.objects - where object names have to be unique within a schema.
This doesn't
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #T1, #T2

CREATE TABLE #T1 ([ID] INT NOT NULL INDEX IX UNIQUE CLUSTERED)

CREATE TABLE #T2 ([ID] INT NOT NULL  INDEX IX UNIQUE CLUSTERED)

Index names only need to be unique within a table - there is no issue with multiple different tables existing concurrently that share index names. Many of the built in objects share fairly unimaginative index names such as clst as can be seen from.
SELECT name, 
       COUNT(*), 
       type_desc
FROM sys.indexes
GROUP BY name, 
         type_desc
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

SQL Server 2000 didn't even have this restriction and allowed duplicate index names within a table. If you were in this position resolving this was a required change before upgrading to 2005.

I deleted my post - you are correct re #naming. Though I swear the #temp index name fixed a problem somewhere, I just cannot remember where. Anyway, giving you a thumbs up.
